# Why is the Result object wrapped in another Result?

Tags: kotlin, testing, junit, jvm

When using a `ParameterizedTest` annotation with a source containing an "Result" type class, the type of the parameter is not the same as the argument.

```kotlin
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource
import java.util.stream.Stream

class testTest() {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun streamOfArguments(): Stream<Arguments?>? {
            return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of(Result.success(true)) // Type Result<Boolean>
            )
        }
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("streamOfArguments")
    fun testArgumentParameter(
      argumentFromStream: Result<Result<Boolean>> // Wrapped in an additional successful `Result`
    ) {
        println(argumentFromStream::class)
        argumentFromStream.onSuccess{
          println(it)
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you change the test parameter to by `argumentFromtStream: Result<Boolean>` it works. My guess is that this is because [`Result`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/) is a [value class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html), and JUnit has some workaround code that will wrap/unwrap value classes on demand to match the requested type. Presumably it does this recursively, even if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @aSemy that is incorrect, the type for Result is checked in runtime, try doing an assertion with the parameter set to Result<Boolean>

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. When I copy and paste your code and run it locally, it runs without error, both with `Result<Boolean>` and `Result<Result<Boolean>>`. What error are you seeing? What versions of Kotlin and JUnit are you using?

Comment: If you actually use the result type (not just println the value as in my example in the question) you'll see it throws a type casting exception, example: `argumentFromStream.onSuccess{ println(it) }`

Comment: Ahh I understand now. Adding `assertTrue(argumentFromStream.getOrNull() ?: false)` to your example would make it more clear :). I think this is [a bug in JUnit](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2703), which is written in Java and so don't understand Kotlin's value classes. You could try writing a [manual converter](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-argument-conversion-explicit), or create a class `data class TestData(val arg: Result<Boolean>)` that will contain all the args, so JUnit isn't involved with converting them.

Comment: That sound like a answer :), sorry, but I don't understand how JUnit is doing the conversions, but using a data class won't require the conversions.
I'll take a look at the converter although it sounds silly to write a converter for something like "Result<T>"

Comment: Tried using a small custom converter now with the exact same behavior in the test method unfortunately.